# JQuery Updating Problem?

Tags: jquery

I can only get the functions `getRating();` and `getRatingText();` to update without reloading the web page. But the other functions `getRatingText2();` and `getRatingAvg();` wont update until I reload the web page.

How can I get all the functions to update without reloading my web page?

Here is the JQuery script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#rating-text").length) {

      getRatingText();

      getRatingText2();

      getRatingAvg();

      getRating();
    }


    function getRatingText(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "do=getavgrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                // add rating text
                $("#rating-text").text(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }



        function getRatingText2(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "update.php",
                data: "do=getavgrate2",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(result) {

                    $("#rating-text2").text(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("some error occured, please try again later");
                }
            });
        }



        function getRatingAvg(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "update.php",
                data: "do=getavgrate3",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(result) {

                    $("#grade-avg").text(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("some error occured, please try again later");
                }
            });
        }


    function getRating(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "do=getrate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {

                $("#current-rating").css({ width: "" + result + "%" });

                $("#rating-text").text(getRatingText());
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });
    }


    // link handler
    $('#ratelinks li a').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "update.php",
            data: "rating="+$(this).text()+"&do=rate",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {

                $("#ratelinks").remove();

                getRating();
            },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("some error occured, please try again later");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The $(document).ready function is only called when the page is finished loading and the dom is ready. getRatingText2() and getRatingAvg() are only called in that function so that is why they are only called when the page is loaded.

Perhaps they should be called in the click event along with you other functions or from getRating()? (getRating(); and getRatingText(); )

Comment: If you want getRatingText2() and getRatingAvg() to update when they click the rate link then simply place them in your $('#ratelinks li a').click function.

Answer (score 0):

Are your "click" items generated dynamically? If they are, use
`$('#ratelinks li a').live('click', funcion())`

Comment: pnut, it sounds like you may have more than jQuery issues. Are you sure CSS is correct? Have you tried applying the `live` or `click` function to JUST a specific link id?